# How to resolve Zone Aware Promise in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular

How to prevent Zone Aware Promise in angular?

The following code is returning `ZoneAwarePromise`

```
    const versions = await itemDetails.imageSamples.map(({ item, images }) => {
      const mapped = Promise.all(
        images.map((image) =>
          this.pushImage(image, `items/${id}/images/`)
        )
      );


      return { item, images };


    });

// here I'm mapping twice. & I suspect this double mapping is causing the Zone Aware Promise

// I tried this way also:


    const versions = await Promise.all( itemDetails.imageSamples.map(({ item, images }) => {
      const mapped = Promise.all(  ---> // this inside mapping is causing zone  aware promise
        images.map((image) =>  
          this.pushImage(image, `items/${id}/images/`) 
        )
      );


      return { item, images };


    }));
```

The following code is returning the promise correctly (i.e without any Zone Aware Promise).

```
    const samples = await Promise.all(
      itemDetails.samples.map((sample) =>
        this.pushImage(sample, `items/${id}/samples/`)
      )
    );

// here I'm mapping only once. So there is no Zone Aware Promise.
```

This is the push Image async function.

```
  async pushImage(image, basePath) {
    const imgId = this.angularDatabase.createPushId();
    const route = `${basePath}${imgId}`;
    const imageRef = this.angularFireStorage.ref(route);
    
    return await concat(
      imageRef.put(image.image).snapshotChanges().pipe(ignoreElements()),
      defer(() => imageRef.getDownloadURL())
    )
      .pipe(
        map(
          (url) => (
             { ...image, url }
          )
        )
      )
      .toPromise();
  }
```

**SO it seems like mapping twice is creating issue**

Can someone suggest a workaround?

**Update**

```
const promises = Promise.all(
      itemDetails.promises.map(({ details, images }) => ({
        details,
        images: Promise.all(
          images.map((image) =>
            this.pushImage(image, `items/${id}/images/`)
          )
        ),
      }))
    );
```

Comment: If you're mapping twice, you also need to `Promise.all` twice. (Unless you want to flatten the array of promises)

Comment: Yes. I tried that way also. Still getting zone aware promise inside that!!

Comment: What do you mean by "*inside that*"? Thanks for updating the code. It shows you're not actually using the `mapped` promise anywhere though, especially you're not waiting for it.

Comment: You see this ```const mapped = Promise.all(
        images.map((image) =>
          this.pushImage(image, `items/${id}/images/`)
        )
      );``` is causing the Zone Aware Promise... the outside promise is returning correctly.

Comment: Can you show me an example of how I should do the above one??

Comment: Of course, `Promise.all` returns a promise. You haven't `await`ed it anywhere. What do you want to do with the `mapped` values, ignore them?

Comment: Yes. I want the mapped promises...

Comment: Where should I put the await inside the map ?

Comment: Can you show me an example of how this should be done?

Comment: ```const promises = Promise.all(
      itemDetails.promises.map(({ details, images }) => ({
        details,
        images: Promise.all(
          images.map((image) =>
            this.pushImage(image, `items/${id}/images/`)
          )
        ),
      }))
    );```